# How to use ogr2ogr's spat_extent keyword to clip a layer of a GPKG file?

Tags: gdal, clip, ogr2ogr, geopackage

I am trying to clip geometries within a GPKG file using a bounding box. I write an L-shaped line to a file:

```
import geopandas as gpd
import shapely.geometry

l = shapely.geometry.LineString([[0,2],[0,-2],[2,-2]])
gpd.GeoSeries(l).to_file("test.gpkg",layer="line")
```

I try to clip my L-shaped line using [`ogr2ogr`](https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html):

```
ogr2ogr \
    -spat -1 -1 1 1 \
    -clipsrc spat_extent \
    test_cut.gpkg test.gpkg
```

Despite using the [`spat_extent` keyword](https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html#cmdoption-ogr2ogr-clipsrc), `test_cut.gpkg` ends up containing the same geometry as the original `test.gpkg`.

To visualize my aim, I created this plot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ax = gpd.GeoSeries(l).plot(color="red")
gpd.GeoSeries(shapely.geometry.box(-1,-1,1,1)).plot(ax=ax)
```

[image]

I would like `test_cut.gpkg` only to contain the line which is within the `-1,-1,1,1` bounding box, ie the part of the red line which is within the blue square.

I also tried:

```
ogr2ogr \
    -spat -1 -1 1 1 \
    -clipsrc spat_extent \
    -clipdstlayer line \
    test_cut.gpkg test.gpkg
```

but result is the same, the L-shaped line fully makes it to `test_cut.gpkg`.

**How can I use the `spat_extent` keyword to clip a GPKG layer?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like there is a regression in GDAL 3.8 that breaks the clipping. I filed a bug report for it here: https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/issues/9013

As a workaround, you can disable usage of the arrow API by specifying config option `OGR2OGR_USE_ARROW_API=NO`. Using ogr2ogr this should be possible like this:

```
ogr2ogr \
    --config OGR2OGR_USE_ARROW_API NO \
    -spat -1 -1 1 1 \
    -clipsrc spat_extent \
    test_cut.gpkg test.gpkg
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to figure this out without being very familiar with the GDAL codebase? The only place I find `OGR2OGR_USE_ARROW_API` is https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/autotest/utilities/test_ogr2ogr_lib.py.

Comment: No, I'm afraid not. Normally the parameter also should never be used because the only difference should be a difference in performance. But, it is still a very new change and apparently there are still some bugs popping up :-(.

Comment: The issue has already been fixed by the GDAL developers and has just been released in [GDAL 3.8.3](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/v3.8.3/NEWS.md#utilities-1).